# Passing stored procedure Parameter to Crystal Report in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate edition
Sql Server:  2005
The problem is , when i pass a parameter value to crystal report , in first go it show me the exact result in browser but when i click on next page it shows null result.

**following is a simple stored procedure**

```
Create Procedure SP_SearchDDO @ddo varchar(10)
{
   As
   Begin
        Select * from PData where DDO = @ddo
   end
}
```

**Here is the code**

```
Protected void btn_search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ReportDocument rptDoc = new ReportDocument();
   string rptPath = Server.MapPath("ddoReprt.rpt");
   rptDoc.Load(rptPath);
   rptDoc.SetParameterValue("@ddo", "ABC");
   CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptDoc;
}
```

When i click on search button in browser it shows exact **"ABC"** required result, when i click on next page button (Crystal report viewer embedded button ), then "ABC" parameter result lost and show null result.
Plz tell me where i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue, following are the steps

In crystal report expand Parameter Fields ==> @parameterValue ==> click edit
here change **List of values** to dynamic and click ok as given in following figure.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

have u tried

ReuseParameterValuesOnRefresh="True" for the crystalreprotviewer ?

Comment: @KhuramJan try add this too AutoDataBind="true"

Comment: still same issue, here i want to add, during crystal report design in preview it ask a parameter value here i set Null, if i provide value suppose "xyz" then instead of null it shows only "xyz" , means same issue will null or either if i provide a parameter value

Comment: the value lost when postback. similar case when do dynamic bind of crystal report. if u try push that portion of code to page_load or init, you will it won't lost anymore.